Simplify $\arctan(x + b)$ where $b$ is a constant positive integer?
I was wondering if it was possible to simplify $\arctan(x + b)$ so that I can factor out the $x$ from the expression entirely.
I tried searching a rule for the $\arctan$ of a sum but came up empty-handed. Any help is appreciated!
For context, the term is inside a summation:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^l \arctan((10x - 10b_n)^4 - 2(10x - 10b_n)^2) $$

I would be surprised if this would work.

No, there is no such simplification.
